# Interval Spanned by $(n+1)$ points in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, spline

Suppose that we have a real valued function $f(x)$ that has local support, i.e. it's non-zero just for some values of $x$.
If you are familiar with B-splines, this function $f$ can be interpreted as a B-spline of order $n$ "that is non-zero in the interval spanned by $(n+1)$ knots".**The Elements of Statistical Learning** (Hastie, et.at.,p.188)

My question is, isn't all the real line spanned by two points? I've always seen "span" as something related to vectors, not to merely scalars.

So what's wrong with the "local support" condition of the B-splines? Is this a improper use of the term "span"?

Comment: All the real line is spanned by a single nonzero value. The support of each basis function is the **convex hull** of $d+2$ consecutive knots where $d$ is the spline degree. Your $n$ must be the spline order if each basis is defined by $n+1$ knots.

Comment: you are right, it's not degree, but order. edited

Comment: When saying "the convex hull spanned by points" or "the interval spanned by numbers" the meaning of "span" is different from the linear algebra meaning. It is widely used though and I wouldn't call it improper.